# Get/use autoincremented Primary Key of a new record as a Foreign Key for a record in another table

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My question is specific to SQLAlchemy, but knowing how to do this in any sql language would be great too.

I am trying to create/add 2 records at the same time to 2 different tables:

The 1st (parent) record will have a generated (autoincrement=True) Primary Key, and I would like the 2nd (child) record to have a column that is a Foreign Key to the first record's Primary Key. My problem is that I do not know how to get the generated Primary Key when the first record is added to its table so that I can use that value as a Foreign Key in my second record (which is in another table).

```
Ex: 

parent table:
[pk_id, name, date]
[55, "value", "value"]

child table:
[id, fk_id, color, quantity]
[300, 55, "value", "value"]
```

I need to get that generated 55 from the parent table and use it as the fk_id when I create the child record.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inserted_primary_key` to find the primary key of the most recently inserted record.

https://kite.com/python/docs/sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key

According to the docs it's auto-populated depending on your databse backend, here's an example from https://overiq.com/sqlalchemy-101/crud-using-sqlalchemy-core/

```py
ins = insert(customers)

r = conn.execute(ins, 
    first_name = "Tim", 
    last_name = "Snyder", 
    username = "timsnyder", 
    email = "timsnyder@mail.com",
    address = '1611 Sundown Lane',
    town = 'Langdale'
)
r.inserted_primary_key
```

Comment: Does this require a return trip to the client followed by a subsequent query, or can I execute a single instruction set all on the db?